# How do I handle a call which is prone to hanging the current thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, db2, odbc, freeze

I have a serious problem with this line of code:

`new OdbcConnection(builder.ConnectionString)`

Our customer takes his DB2 database down every night to backup it and sometimes this causes our Code to hang at this line of code. Even after an hour of waiting it's still stuck. Unfortunately this error can not be reproduced at will and occurs only some days at random.

There is a [KB article at Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274569) for a problem like this but this fix is not applicable because our version of MDAC should be newer.

I found no other means to fix the problem so I want to start a new thread, let it try to create the object which can be killed after a timeout.
I could use Tasks but a task can only be canceled with a cancellation token which can not be evaluated because the Task consists of one line of code in which it either hangs or not.

While searching how to abort a task everybody says you can not abort a task and you should not use Thread.Abort.

However in this case I don't see any other possibility than this. Can anyone suggest a better way of handling this hanging code?

Comment: How about cleaning up what you can, instantiating another copy of your process and immediately force-terminating the current one with Environment.Exit?  The new instance will run up and, finding the DB unavailable, will presumably periodically retry until the DB does come up and then run on mormally, (till next hangup:).

Comment: It's just one job of many which is hanging. So I can not restart the service at will. And I still would need a controlling instance.

Answer (score 1):

So no suggestions here, my take on this problem  is:

```
private OdbcConnection ResolveConnection(OdbcConnectionStringBuilder connectionString)
{
    if (!_connections.ContainsKey(connectionString.Dsn))
    {
        OdbcConnection connection = null;

        var newOdbcConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        var evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        var connectionThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString);
                }
                finally
                {
                    evt.Set();
                }
            });
        connectionThread.Start();
        var isOk = evt.WaitOne(newOdbcConnectionTimeout);

        if (!isOk || connection == null)
        {
            connectionThread.Abort();
            const string messageFormat = "Timeout of {0} reached while creating OdbcConnection to {1}.";
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(messageFormat, newOdbcConnectionTimeout, connectionString));
        }

        _connections.Add(connectionString.Dsn, connection);
    }

    return _connections[connectionString.Dsn];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember any more. It's 4 years ago :(

Answer (score -1):

It seems like starting a new thread simply because there is a condition which hangs the code will only compound your problems, and it is certainly not the purpose of a thread.  I would suggest a Try/Catch/Finally block to prevent the code from hanging.

Comment: Try/Catch/Finally will probably not help at all.  If the call blocks, the Catch/Finally will not be executed.